# Hello Android application does not show in the Android Emulator

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-emulator, android-widget

I know this has been asked before, and I've looked at all of the other questions but the responses don't seem to help me.

I'm performing the Hello Android tutorial on the android sdk website. I've done everything they said but when the emulator runs, there is no hello android application or widget in the applications menu or anywhere. I repeat, the emulator runs, I unlocked the screen, looked in the applications but it is just not there.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you. (Also, logcat doesnt show anything).

Comment: sometimes that's happens , the emulator disconnected before the installation of the application , try to re install it again and again or try to execute it on a phone

Comment: can you post your manifest file ?

Answer (score 1):

Kind of a vague problem, I would assume you're using eclipse.

1) Does it launch the emulator when you run it if the emulator is off?

2) Which Hello Android tutorial are you looking at?  (I.E off the Android site?)

3) Have you checked the console to see what it's doing, any strange messages?

Comment: Yes, the emulator launches. Yes, the one off the android site. And here is what the console displays: [2011-06-19 15:06:34 - Hello Android] Android Launch!
[2011-06-19 15:06:34 - Hello Android] adb is running normally.
[2011-06-19 15:06:34 - Hello Android] Performing com.example.helloandroid.HelloAndroid activity launch
[2011-06-19 15:06:34 - Hello Android] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'my_avd'
[2011-06-19 15:06:34 - Hello Android] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'my_avd'

Comment: You're missing a few pieces after running the emulator.  It should upload and install it, then obviously launch it.

Comment: Sorry, I was also going to say, you should check the AVD version and maybe redo the Create and AVD section again.  Relaunching the software and possibly a restart as well if you haven't since installing Eclipse and the emulator/SDKs etc.

Comment: I've checked it all and am stuck...maybe I should wipe everything and just try reinstalling it all.

Comment: Maybe you should download the USB driver for Eclipse and try it right on the device first, just to rule that out.  Besides making sure you follow all the steps, it's a hard problem to diagnose.